# Was Marcus Marcellus faced with Viridomarus or Britomartus?

Tags: ancient-history, ancient-rome, roman-republic

I seem to have come to a discrepancy, as I'm sure a lot have, concerning the event in which Marcus Claudius Marcellus is supposedly meant to have slain the King of the Insubres in 222 B.C.E.

Plutarch tells us in his book ['Life of Marcellus'](http://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/E/Roman/Texts/Plutarch/Lives/Marcellus%2a.html) p. 449 - 451

> "From thence Britomartus the king, taking with him ten thousand of the
>   Gaesatae, ravaged the country about the Po." - p.449
>
> "Meanwhile the king of the Gauls [Britomartus] espied him, and judging
>   from his insignia that he was the commander, rode far out in front of
>   the rest and confronted him, shouting challenges and brandishing his
>   spear. His stature exceeded that of the other Gauls, and he was
>   conspicuous for a suit of armour which was set off with gold and
>   silver and bright colours and all sorts of broideries; it gleamed like
>   lightning. 2 Accordingly, as Marcellus surveyed the ranks of the
>   enemy, this seemed to him to be the most beautiful armour, and he
>   concluded that it was this which he had vowed to the god. He therefore
>   rushed upon the man, and by a thrust of his spear which pierced his
>   adversary's breastplate, and by the impact of his horse in full
>   career, threw him, still living, upon the ground, where, with a second
>   and third blow, he promptly killed him." -p.451
>
> "The first [to win the Spolia Opima] was Romulus, who despoiled Acron
>   the Caeninensian the second was Cornelius Cossus, who despoiled
>   Tolumnius the Tuscan; and after them Marcellus, who despoiled
>   Britomartus, king of the Gauls; but after Marcellus, no man." - p.455

Florus tells us in his writings ['Epitome of Roman History'](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Epitome_of_Roman_History/Book_1#1) Chap. IV.

Although apparently sourced mainly from Livy - Florus tells us that:

> "When Viridomarus was their king, they vowed the arms of the Romans to
>   Vulcan; but their vows had a very different result; for Marcellus,
>   having killed their king, hung up his arms to Jupiter Feretrius, being
>   the third spolia opima since those of Romulus, the father of the
>   city."

Livy Tells us in an excerpt of Book XX - The History of Rome ['Periochae'](http://www.livius.org/li-ln/livy/periochae/periochae016.html)

He claims:

> "Gauls from across the Alps invaded Italy and were defeated. It is
>   said that during this war, the Roman people and its Latin allies
>   employed 800,000 soldiers. For the first time, Roman armies crossed
>   the Po and the Gallic Insubres, defeated in battle, were defeated in a
>   series of battles. They surrendered. Consul Marcus Claudius Marcellus
>   killed the leader of the Gallic Insubres, Vertomarus, and returned
>   with the supreme booty."

Adrian Goldsworthy seems to source Plutarch, suggesting that his argument might be more reliable.

Has there been any recent conclusive evidence, or is this chiefly a mix up of name as opposed to character?

Comment: No, Plutarch continues to differ from other sources on this point. I don't think he will change his mind. :-) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Clastidium

Comment: Okay, I understand that he can't. I also don't understand why you've linked me to the wikipedia article of the battle. The sources were added by me on the same day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is enough similarity in the names that this would appear to be a transcription error, for which true resolution would require referencing the oldest extant manuscripts for both sources. [Manuscript transcription](http://www.canterburytalesproject.org/pubs/op2-transcribertale.pdf) is an extremely complex process, and many medieval monks performing transcription are now believed to have been only marginally literate; errors were common.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It has been suggested that if you take away the vowels you are left with 'brt/vrd/vrt' which might imply a slight difference of translation somewhere down the line.